# Promise in foreach with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a problem with a promise,

```
$scope.refreshProject = function () {
    project.getAll().then(function(results) {
        angular.forEach(results, function(project) {
            project_path = project.path;
            project_file = project.file;
            project_id = project.id;

            console.log(project);
            console.log('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file);

            $http.get('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file)
                .then(function(res){
                    var project = new Project();
                    project.update(project_id, { 'content': res.data });
                });

        });

        $scope.refresh();
    });
};
```

My $http.get doesn't work, the

> console.log('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file);

return

> 'http:///'

my variables are empties.

**project.model.js**

```
Project.prototype.getAll = function () {
    return ProjectService.getAll();
};
```

**project.service.js**

```
this.getAll = function (params) {
    var projects = [];
    return db.selectAll('projects').then(function(results) {
        for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            projects.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        return projects;
    });
};
```

How can I execute my $http request when I have the params from project.path and project.file are ok ?

> SOLVED

```
    project.getAll().then(function(results) {
        angular.forEach(results, function(project) {
            (function(project) {
                var project_id = project.id;

                if (project.path) {
                    var promise = $http.get(project.path + '/' + project.file)
                        .then(function(res){
                            var project = new Project();
                            console.log(res.data);
                            project.update(project_id, { 'content': res.data });
                        });
                }

                promises.push(promise);
            })(project);
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(function() {
            $scope.refresh();
            console.log('refresh() ok');
        });
    });
```

Comment: use `$q.all` or `Promise.all`

Comment: Did you check `console.log(results)`? Is it correct?

Comment: It's not good idea to send request inside loop.Your performance will be very low, sometimes your application can crash, that's why you need to send the result (as array) in 1 http request

Answer (score 1):

First, check that `results` contains the correct data -- those `console.logs` being empty suggests that it isn't, and that `projectService.getAll()` isn't returning what you expect.

Assuming that is working as expected, you have three separate variables all named "project":

```
    project.getAll().then(function(results) {
//  ^^^^^^^ 1
        angular.forEach(results, function(project) {
//                                        ^^^^^^^ 2
            project_path = project.path;
//                         ^^^^^^^ 2
//          ...
            $http.get('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file).then(function(res){
                var project = new Project();
//                  ^^^^^^^ 3
```

Off the top of my head I honestly have no idea which of those  is overwriting which of the others, especially since there's async code involved -- but I'd bet a nickel that at least one of them must be.

If nothing else changing those to different names will make maintenance and debugging easier...

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: depending on how `angular.forEach` works, wrapping your callback like so might do it.
(otherwise all callbacks might be called with the last version of `project`, more detail here [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example))

```
$scope.refreshProject = function () {
  project.getAll().then(function(results) {
    angular.forEach(results, function(project) {
      (function(project) {
        project_path = project.path;
        project_file = project.file;
        project_id = project.id;

        console.log(project);
        console.log('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file);

        $http.get('http://' + project_path + '/' + project_file)
          .then(function(res){
            var project = new Project();
            project.update(project_id, { 'content': res.data });
          });
      })(project);
    });

    $scope.refresh();
  });
};
```